# Use prediction interval to get possible values for x given y?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, confidence-interval

I have the linear model $y = \beta x + \alpha + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon$ i.i.d normally distributed with variance $\sigma^2$.
I fit the linear regression using OLS and compute a prediction interval et confidence $\gamma$ for a new observation $x_0$ using the formula:
$\widehat{\alpha}+\widehat{\beta} x_0 \pm t_{n-2 ; 1-\gamma / 2} \cdot \widehat{\sigma} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\left(x_0-\bar{x}\right)^2}{S S_X}}$
with $S S_X=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(x_i-\bar{x}\right)^2$

I'm now wondering if I can solve the two bounds for $x_0$ to obtain a range of possible values for $x_0$ at confidence level $\gamma$.

Usually, when testing multiple points, one has to use a Bonferroni correction to keep the significance level. Since I'm trying to solve for $x_0$ and get an interval(infinitely many values), I'm wondering if I should also have any sort of correction on the $t$ statistic.

Comment: With your expression for the prediction interval at $x_0$: as $x_0$ changes (a) the centre of the interval at $\hat \alpha +\hat \beta x_0$ changes  (linearly with $x_0$) and (b) the width of the interval  $2t_{n-2 ; 1-\gamma / 2} \cdot \widehat{\sigma} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\left(x_0-\bar{x}\right)^2}{S S_X}}$ changes (wider when $\left(x_0-\bar{x}\right)^2$ is larger).  This makes sense intuitively: linear and estimated better in the middle.  So what do you mean when you say "I think I would need a prediction interval for the whole regression line for what I'm trying to do"?

Comment: I've seen that when people test different values of x_0 they use a Bonferroni correction. Since I want to solve for x_0 and find a confidence interval (with infinitely many values), I'm wondering if I shouldn't have any sort of correction like that on the t-statistic. Thanks for your comment I edited my question

Comment: This is a prediction interval for each $x_0$.  You would expect about $\gamma$ of the corresponding $y_0$s to be outside the prediction intervals: see for example the red lines on the chart at another question at  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225652/prediction-interval-vs-confidence-interval-in-linear-regression-analysis.  You can do a single test to check the hypothesis that the proportion of $y_0$s outside the prediction intervals is indeed $\gamma$, but since $\gamma$ is presumably small, you may need a large sample size to get a reasonable power on the test.